# Run the same gradle task multiple times in parallel in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

My java project consists of two modules, `client` and `server`. I am using IntelliJ and gradle. I want to run one server instance and two client instances in parallel. Until now, I have opened three terminal windows with the commands `gradle server:run` and 2x `gradle client:run` and everything worked as expected. Now, I tried the following configuration in IntelliJ:

- Gradle:

  - Run Server
  - Run Client 1
  - Run Client 2
- Compound:

  - Run Two Clients (contains the three gradle configurations)

However, if I run the compound configuration, only one client is executed. The other client prints `Executing task 'run'...` but does not actually run. Only when I terminate the first client, the other client starts. Is there a way to run both client tasks in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue: [IDEA-270755](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270755) Gradle Task with 'Allow Parallel Run' option hangs when executed subsequently.